# 'signinL' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs, redux, navbar

signinL is declared but never used error, please help, it is an import that I have taken and used as a component still it's showing as error

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import signinL from './signinL'

const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav-wrapper grey darken-3">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to='/' className="brand-logo">My Peral</Link>
               <signinL />
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: What is the question? It is true that compiler gave you correct insight.

Comment: It's not an error, that's a warning that is caused by the line `import signinL from './signinL'.  It's telling you that you have that import but are never using what is imported, so it's a useless import and you can safely remove it.  Best practice is to not have any unused imports.